# Bind method name to mysql where clause?

Tags: mysql, scala, encryption, playframework

I used two table.

table1: `Employees` table I have two columns ***id, employees_id***(Type: Long)

table2: `Salary` table I have two columns ***id, employees_encrpted_id***(Type: String)

**Note**: 
**1.** The two table common field is **employees_id** in `Employees` table(Here we store in employees id)  and **employees_encrpted_id** in `Salary` table(we use encryption method to encrypt employees id then store it)

**2.** I have decrypted method(name is `decrypt`). It's possible to bind that method to mysql query. I tried like this

"**select * from employees as emp, salary as s where emp.employees_id = CAST("+`decrypt`("s.employees_encrpted_id")+"AS UNSIGNED)**"

but throws error "[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]"

Comment: Assuming you don't do this already, it would be a lot easier to (just) encrypt the salaries (probably including the id into the passphrase, to prevent two identical salaries to look the same). And it is actually a lot safer, because oftentimes one can conclude from other information which id it can (or cannot) be, e.g. if the table contains a history, the date of first entry corresponds to the date of joining the firm, promotions corresponds to raises, number of entries probably relate to occupation time at the firm, the highest salary probably belongs to the boss (or the dba), ...

Answer (score 0):

if you have to handle encrypted ID columns, you have these options:

1) load the tables that are referenced into memory (out of your DB, into your application), then decrypt, then join ... obviously this has a little flaw: you are not capable of using your DBMS for the join, or for groupings, or for aggregation, etc if said things rely on the encrypted column to be available in decrypted form

2) load the first table, ENCRYPT the ids, and create a temp table containing the first table with its IDs encrypted, run your query against the temp table + other tables with encrypted IDs, and drop the temp table... obviously again there is a little flaw: your DBMS gains knowledge about what it is not supposed to know: the relation between the encrypted and unencrypted ids...

3) implement your encryption/decryption as a stored function, and call it with a key everytime you use the relationship ... again there is a flaw: your DBMS will need to call this function for every id value to obtain the decrypted/encrypted value, which is likely a performance impact you or your users can at most barely, if at all, tolerate

in the end you will most likely find out that the whole security gain of your encrypted IDs will be lost due to the fact that the key has to be stored on the applicationserver, or can be intercepted on the DBMS side, and the whole deal with implementing a encrypted ID columns was merely for fun and not for profit